# How to recover android alias name and password

Tags: android, android-keystore

We can recover keystore password by doing a bruteforce by the tool https://code.google.com/p/android-keystore-password-recover/

Thats understandable, but how to recover the alias name and alias password? The alias password is also needed to proceed with updates and new versions of the application.

Answer (score 1):

If you cracked the container password you can simply read the alias with the jarsigner tool. The next step would be to crack the password of the private key which should work like the container password.

Comment: So, if you please elaborate further, that I can use the same mentioned google tool to crack/bruteforce the alias password? Secondly, the `container` is the `keystore`? and that includes the `alias` ?

Comment: I just took a look to that tool. It seems that this tool does not support it. I guess that the code could be simple extended.

Comment: can you explain what is alias. I think I am confusing it. What do i need to get first. can you elaborate how to approach / recover both

Comment: I'm no expert but how I understood it: The key store is a encrypted container. Each key has a public and a private key. The private key is also encrypted which requires a second (optional other) password. However the as you can store multiple keys in a key store you need to identify the different keys the simplest way is using an alias, which is just a simple marker.

Comment: hmm. ok thanks... so how to recover the alias name and alias password?

Comment: You can read the alias if you cracked the container. I have no idea how to do this with that project you found. But there must be a function to open the key store if this was successful you can output/store the container password and start crack the private keys with the same method you used for cracking the container.